# Need help setting up this Mercury Vagrant server stack

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I'm currently setting up a server stack on Digitalocean Virtual cloud server to include:
Percona DB (MySQL)
HHVM (Default PHP Parser)
PHP-FPM (Backup PHP Parser)
Nginx
Varnish (Running by default)
Memcached and APC
Clean WordPress Install (Latest Version)
WP-CLI

I've been following the steps here:
https://github.com/zach-adams/hgv-deploy-full?files=1

I'm struggling to understand how to carry out step 6 to 9.

Can some please tell the code i'd need to type to complete these steps.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Welcome to SO! What are the specific errors or issues? What have you tried? See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

6 - Move into hg-deploy-full  means change the directory to that folder that you just imported with git:

cd ~/hgv-deploy-full/

make sure you got there by typing:

pwd

then do the ls command to list all folders and files:

ls

once there, you will see the hosts file listed as "hosts" with other folders above it

7 - Edit the hosts file contents to change yourhostname.com to your host name:

nano hosts

Type in to set your-domain-name.com in place of "yourhostname.com" that is set up by default in the file.

Save the file and exit:

Save the file and exit:
CTRL-X
then answer yes to save:
Y
press enter to confirm:
Enter

8 - Edit the name of the yourhostname.com file in the host_vars folder to your hostname. If you have more than one website that you want to install on this server copy the current one and name it the hostname of the website:

ls -la /host_vars/

You should see the yourhostname.com file, rename it:

mv yourhostname.com domain.com

9 - Change your sites specific information including passwords inside the hostname file inside the host_vars directory:

nano domain.com

Type in domain.com file your specific info to change the defaults listed in the file for a WordPress database, etc.

Save the file and exit:
CTRL-X
then answer yes to save:
Y
press enter to confirm:
Enter

Proceed to step 10.

I hope this helps you, I'm pretty rusty...

Comment: when editing the hosts file and the yourhostname.com file -- do not use cd

Comment: You could also just use this improved project of the same: https://github.com/carlalexander/debops-wordpress